# OnSelectedIndexChange not firing even with autopostback=true

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, postback

Ok I'm a little stumped here. I have an asp:Dropdownlist on the page. It gets populated via a web service call like this:

```
Ajax.GetSubDevelopments(developmentId, function (results) {
    var subDevelopments = $j("#<%=ddlMinorAssociation.ClientID %>");
    subDevelopments.empty();
    $j('<option />', { value: "-1", text: "Select a sub association" }).appendTo(subDevelopments);
        $j.each(results, function (index, value) {
            $j('<option />', { value: value.SubDevelopmentID, text: value.Name }).appendTo(subDevelopments);
        });
        subDevelopments.show();
    });
```

The actual control itself looks like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMinorAssociation" 
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlMinorAssociation_SelectedIndexChanged" 
   AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" CssClass="hidden">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The intent is that when the user selects a subdevelopment, it will postback and then bind a datalist of results. Now the page is posting back, Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET") even says that it was posting back due to the drop down list. However, none of the code in my ddlMinorAssociation_SelectedIndexChanged function is being run. Here is that code:

```
protected void ddlMinorAssociation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("hi");
}
```

Can anyone offer some insight as to what is going on???

Comment: How did you confirm that it's not firing?

Comment: Two ways. 1) My Response.Write is never being written to the page. 2) I ran a debug session with a breakpoint on that Response.Write line. Its never hit.

Comment: Populate the drop down list in the code behind and select a value as a test. I'm suspecting the ajax loading is causing the problem.

Comment: I'm actually refactoring the code from a version where this was bound in the code behind (client requested a feature that requires AJAX). When its bound in the code behind, it fires properly.

Comment: That's my point. I can't confirm at the moment, but if I remember correctly modifying the drop down selections via javascript causes the server-side events to break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is related to the fact that when the page loaded, there were no elements in the dropdown list and ViewState didn't have any information of selected items; therefore, when it posts back, it determines that there hasn't been any IndexChanged event to fire.

The fact that it posts back is just because the Autoposback property is set to true which basically fires a normal form submit.

If you want this to work, change the AutoPostback property to false and hook code to the onchange event instead, then fire another Ajax request to whatever method you need to execute on the server side and bind the data on the client side.

Comment: Ya I think you hit the nail on the head. Unfortunately the code I need to execute is another databind...a much more complicated databind. I'm going to attempt a hack with a hidden field and __doPostBack.

Comment: @Icestorm0141 I know this is bit late.. But I have similar issue. I have another databind from dropdown. Any same code showing how you fixed your issue will be of great help

Answer (score 2):

Server-side, you dropdown list does not have any items. It cannot fire OnSelectedIndexChanged event because its index has not changed - it has no items to give it a meaningful current index value.